# Java - Making a Checkbox Deactivate a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, jcheckbox

I'm newbie in programming java, but, I need to make a CheckBox Deactivate a JTextField when it's checked, but i don't have success in this, i tried `if(JTextField.isSelected())` but unsuccessfully.
Here is my CheckBox code:

```
JCheckBox chckbxMostrarSoma = new JCheckBox("Mostrar Soma?");
    chckbxMostrarSoma.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    chckbxMostrarSoma.setSelected(true);
    chckbxMostrarSoma.setBounds(6, 86, 123, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxMostrarSoma);
```

I make that JFrame using WindowBuilder (Its so boring to make a JFrame with their own hands)

Comment: 1) `chckbxMostrarSoma.setBounds(6, 86, 123, 23);`  Use layouts! 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a listenere to your `JCheckBox`. That listener should catch the event of selection change and then deactivate the `JTextField`.

If you do not understand anything above, please read the[swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your ckeckbox

```
chckbxMostrarSoma.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if(chckbxMostrarSoma.isSelected()){
                textfield.setEnabled(false);
            } else{
                textfield.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }

    });
```

Change the word "textfield" in the code to your textfield.